# Test for instantiation of a mocked class in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to make my tests "real" unittests in a strict meaning. There shouldn't be any dependencies. All dependencies should be mocked.

The class `Bar` in module `bar` need to be tested. But in some situations it will have a member of type `Foo` from module `foo`. The goal is that the unittest does not have to import `foo` or `foo.Foo`.

My mocking seems to work. But I'm not sure how to test if `Bar()` now does have tried to instantiate `foo.Foo()`. My `assert_called()` in the below example failed with `Expected 'mock' to have been called.`. And that assert also doesn't give me all information's I want.

This is the test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import bar


# The goal ist to test "Bar" wihtout importing "foo.Foo" as an extra dependency
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        mock_foo = mock.Mock()
        bar.foo = mock_foo

        b = bar.Bar(7)

        print('')
        print(f'{mock_foo=}')
        print(f'{b.y=}')

        # Of course this doesn't work, because "foo" is not imported
        # self.assertIsInstance(b.y, foo.Foo)

        print(mock_foo.__dict__)
        mock_foo.assert_called()  # failes

    def test_int(self):
        b = bar.Bar(8)
        self.assertIsInstance(b.y, int)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here comes module `bar`:

```
import foo


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, y):
        if y == 7:
            self.y = foo.Foo(7)
        else:
            self.y = y
```

And this is module `foo`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Comment: Strive to avoid dependencies in the first place. `Bar.__init__` can take an optional argument (defaulting to `foo.Foo`) to call when necessary. Then to test, you need only make a call like `b = bar.Bar(7, mock_foo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're mocking, you should really be using `mock.patch()` to do your patching.

consider, instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import bar


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('foo.Foo')
    def test_bar(self, foo_mock):

        b = bar.Bar(7)

        # This _does_ work, because the patch decorator gives us the patched
        # mock.
        # this is something you should _never_ include in a proper unit test,
        # but here to demonstrate the patching
        self.assertIs(foo_mock, sys.modules['foo'].Foo)

        foo_mock.assert_called_once_with(7)

    def test_no_foo(self):
        for test_val in [0, True, False, None, 13, 666]:
            with self.subTest(test_val=test_val):
                b = bar.Bar(test_val)

                self.assertEqual(b.y, test_val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This includes some additional improvements to the original posted test (not sure if you artificially simplified the tests for posting, though).

 * in `MyTest.test_bar()`, I test that `foo.Foo` is called once, with `7` as the sole argument
 * in `MyTest.test_no_foo()` (renamed), I test more of the interface of the function as it exists, and I test that the value is the expected actual value, not just of the same type